# How to Create a Form Slider displaying different output fields in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to Create a Slider Form that displays different output fields on sliding using Javascript.
Somewhat of this kind.

[image]

Can anyone suggest to me how can I make it or give some links about a similar thing, I could not find googling.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've made one of these in a recent project, I'll show you the code here. Essentially we create two forms and a topper. The topper is always shown, and we use flexbox to split it in half. With a JS onclick() event we can change which of the two forms are shown depending on if the user clicks on the signup header or the login header. Please make sure to try to code this on your own once you understand how the code works - it helps with learning front-end rather than copy-pasting the code and never writing it on your own! : )

```js
function formSelector(selector) {

    let signupElement = document.getElementById("signup")
    let loginElement = document.getElementById("login")

    let signupForm = document.getElementById("signupForm")
    let loginForm = document.getElementById("loginForm")

    if (selector == "signup") {

        signup.classList.add("selectedHeader")
        login.classList.remove("selectedHeader")

        signupForm.classList.add("showForm")
        loginForm.classList.remove("showForm")
    }
    else if (selector == "login") {

        signup.classList.remove("selectedHeader")
        login.classList.add("selectedHeader")

        signupForm.classList.remove("showForm")
        loginForm.classList.add("showForm")
    }
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200&display=swap");

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "poppins", "sans-serif";
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  --primary: rgb(4, 214, 4);
  --primaryShade: rgb(15, 15, 15);
  --secondaryShade: rgb(238, 240, 243);
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-padding: 300px;
}

.formContainer {
  background: var(--secondaryShade);
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.form {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) 0 12px 60px 0;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.formContent {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  display: none;
  animation: floatUp 0.6s;
  position: relative;
}

.formInput {
  border: 1.5px solid rgb(165, 165, 165);
  padding: 10px;
  outline: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin: 18px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-family: "poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.formInput:hover {
  border-color: var(--primary);
}

.formInput:focus {
  border-color: var(--primary);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 3px 36px 0;
}

.formButton {
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin: 20px 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22) 0 12px 24px 0;
  background: var(--primary);
  color: white;
  font-family: "poppins";
  font-weight: bold;
}

.formButton:hover {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14) 0 6px 24px 0,
    inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.247) 0 0 0 10000px;
}

.formButton:focus {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26) 0 12px 36px 0,
    inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.247) 0 0 0 10000px;
  background: var(--primary);
  color: white;
}

.formTopper {
  background: rgb(236, 236, 236);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.formHeader {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.formHeader:hover {
  background: rgb(219, 219, 219);
}

.selectedHeader {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13) 0 6px 45px 0;
}

.selectedHeader:hover {
  background: white;
}

.showForm {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="formTopper">

    <h1 class="formHeader selectedHeader" id="signup" onclick="formSelector('signup')">Signup</h1>
    <h1 class="formHeader" id="login" onclick="formSelector('login')">Login</h1>

  </div>
  <div class="formContent showForm" id="signupForm">

    <input class="formInput" placeholder="Username" />

    <input class="formInput" placeholder="Email" />

    <input class="formInput" placeholder="Passcode" />

    <button class="formButton">Signup</button>

  </div>
  <div class="formContent" id="loginForm">

    <input class="formInput" placeholder="Username" />

    <input class="formInput" placeholder="Passcode" />

    <button class="formButton">Login</button>

  </div>
</div>
```